# Column value missing in BIRT report for Cassandra data source

Tags: java, postgresql, cassandra, report, birt

I am using **BIRT 4.4** plugin for making reports. Report are generated correctly for postgresql data source. Now i am trying to create report for **cassandra data source**. For that i am using script to connect with cassandra. Here is the link for details.

http://birtworld.blogspot.in/2012/09/birt-cassandra-and-hector.html

The problem is,its only return first column values. So the report is incomplete. How can i get the remaining columns values.